# Simpler way of showing, hiding & disabling elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently having this code & looking for a simpler and shorter way of showing, hiding & disabling my elements...

```
$("#chReportData").click(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].checked) {
        $("#reportDataOptions").show();
    } else {
        $("#ReportDataStatusOptions").hide();
        $("#reportDataOptions").hide();
        $('#chkReportPermission').attr('checked', false);
        $('#chReportDataStatus').attr('checked', false);
        $('#chReportDataCummulative').attr('checked', false);
        $('.allowedUpload').attr('checked', false);
        $('.allowedDelete').attr('checked', false);
    }
});

$("#chReportDataStatus").click(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].checked) {
        $("#ReportDataStatusOptions").show();
    } else if ($('#chReportDataCummulative').is('checked')) {
        $("#ReportDataStatusOptions").hide();
        $('.allowedUpload').attr('checked', false);
        $('.allowedDelete').attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        $("#ReportDataStatusOptions").hide();
        $('.allowedUpload').attr('checked', false);
        $('.allowedDelete').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

It works fine, I'm just looking for a simpler way... If you know of a shorter & simpler way, please share...

Comment: Post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use muliple selectors by commas

```
 $("#ReportDataStatusOptions , #reportDataOptions").hide();
 $('#chkReportPermission , #chReportDataStatus , #chReportDataCummulative , .allowedUpload , .allowedDelete').attr('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `show` and `hide` with a boolean check you can use `toggle`.

[jQuery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) can be used to switch visibility on an item like this: `$( ".target" ).toggle();`

Comment: But one problem with `toggle` is that it toggles `show\hide`... Doesn't check whether its hidden or not...

Answer (score 1):

You can go with modular approach.

Write the common things in functions and call them wherever required.

It can be helpful while maintaining the code as well.

Here is your simplied code:

```
$("#chReportData").click(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].checked) {
        $("#reportDataOptions").show();
    } else {
        hide_ReportDataStatusOptions();
        $("#reportDataOptions").hide();
        uncheck_chReportRbtns();
        uncheckAllowedRbtns();
    }
});

$("#chReportDataStatus").click(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].checked) {
        $("#ReportDataStatusOptions").show();
    } else if ($('#chReportDataCummulative').is('checked')) {
        hide_ReportDataStatusOptions();
        uncheckAllowedRbtns();
    } else {
        hide_ReportDataStatusOptions();
        uncheckAllowedRbtns();
    }
});
```

And the corresponding functions:

```
function uncheck_AllowedRbtns(){
    $('.allowedUpload, .allowedDelete').attr('checked', false);    
}
function uncheck_chReportRbtns(){
    var txt = ['Permission', 'DataStatus', 'DataCummulative'];
    for(var i=0; i<txt.length; i++){
        $('#chReport'+txt[i]).attr('checked', false);
    }
}
function hide_ReportDataStatusOptions(){
    $("#ReportDataStatusOptions").hide();
}
```

Comment: This also works, and I will try and familiarize myself with modular approach.. thank you!